# Inconsistant Docker Images

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, apt

I have been using the `python3.9-slim` docker image, and as one of the build steps I install the 3.9 python headers, via `RUN apt-get install python3-dev`.

This worked for years, and then `apt` has changed so that `python3-dev` now installs the headers for Python 3.11 instead of 3.9.

On top of that, `apt install python3.9-dev` is not available.

I kind of didn't expect these things to be changing under the hood, and thought of using docker images as a way of getting reproducible builds.

Would anyone be able to explain how/why that has changed, and how I might better handle this in the future?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mat , yeah, I understand it's a remote repository that _can_ change. But I'm more confused of why it changes

Comment: Hi @freebie, I responded with a solution as an answer. The problem is source image, python3.9 is based on Debian but Debian bookworm doesn't have `python3.9-dev` package, you need an image based on Debian bullseye (that image exists, read the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that python3.9 and python3.9-slim are based on debian bookworm and this distro doesn't have this package (you can check the packages on [bookworm all packages](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/allpackages)).

If you want to have the `python3.9-dev` package, you can use `python:3.9-slim-bullseye` or `python:3.9-bullseye` that is based on debian bullseye (you can check the packages on this distro on [bullseye all packages](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/allpackages))

Comment: Ah ok, so what I hadn't expected was for the `python3.9-slim` image to be updated to be based on `bookworm` once that had become the current version. I had assumed only new releases of python versions would then use that. Thank you for clearing that up.